# Numpy statement instead of double for-loop

Tags: python, loops, numpy, vectorization

My following Python code is very slow, is there a possibility to write this part completely with a Numpy statement?

```
    m = len(self.man_list)
    s = len(self.newnew)

self.zeroMatrix = np.zeros((m,s))

    for k in range(m):
        a1 = self.man_list[k][2]
        b1 = self.man_list[k][0]
        a2 = self.man_list[k][3]
        b2 = self.man_list[k][1]
        for f, part in enumerate(self.extra_list):
            x1 = self.extra_list[f][0]
            y1 = self.extra_list[f][2]
            x2 = self.extra_list[f][1]
            y2 = self.extra_list[f][3]

            first = np.array((x1, y1))
            second = np.array((x2, y2))
            third = np.array((a1, b1))
            forth = np.array((a2, b2))


            dist1 = np.linalg.norm(first - third)
            dist2 = np.linalg.norm(second - forth)
            distance = (dist1 + dist2)

            self.zeroMatrix[k][f] = distance
```

First of all, I create a Matrix with zeros (`self.zeroMatrix`).

`self.man_list` and `self.extra_list` contain the beginning and ending coordinate points of lines.
e.g:

```
self.man_list = [ [ [1,2], [3,4] ],...]

self.extra_list = [ [ [11,30], [4, 10] ],...]
```

I get the distance from every line of the first list to every line of the other list, then I register this distance-value in the `self.zeroMatrix`.

I'm very grateful for your answers!

Comment: third and fourth should probably be outside the loop, then we don't know what extra_list is. Maybe it could work, maybe not.

Comment: But how should that work? Maybe I didn't get what you are meaning, but your idea doesn't seem to improve the execution time, does it..?

Comment: It will, 2 less norms to compute in a loop. Now, the issue is that we don't know the state of your structures, but clearly we need to know if your lists are arrays or just lists, in which case, there is nothing to do.

Comment: ok you are right, it gets a little bit faster, but I think it would simply get a little bit faster, not that much. the lists are normal lists, but I can switch them very easily to arrays with the code: numpy.array(self.man_list)

Comment: Great, then use the axis keyword for the norm function. If you have an array, then you can do the subtraction, and then the norm. So compute first and second in a numpy statement, do the same for third and fourth, and then do the subtraction, compute the norm on the axis.

Comment: Do you mean outside the two for-loops?

Comment: yes, you don't need for loops anymore with numpy arrays.

Comment: Would you eventually write down the code? I don't know how to combine your instruction in one line..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to vectorize your calls:

```
man_list = np.array(self.man_list)
extra_list = np.array(self.extra_list)
```

Then create the sub matrices you need:

```
first = extra_list[:, None, ::2]
second = extra_list[:, None, 1::2]
third = man_list[None, :, 2::-2]
fourth = man_list[None, :, 3::-2]
```

And now, compute the norm on the last axis, axis 2.

```
dist1 = np.linalg.norm(first - third, axis=2)
dist2 = np.linalg.norm(second - fourth, axis=2)
distance = (dist1 + dist2)
```

And now, you **should** have in `distance` the matrix you want.

Comment: but why following error occurs?
Error in this line:  dist1 = np.linalg.norm(first - third, axis=2)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (973,1,2) (1,147,3)

Comment: Seems like I made a mistake somewhere, Do you have more than 4 entries in your list of lists? Added a check.

Comment: BTW `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` is exactly for this purpose

Comment: indeed, the last part could be replaced with it, and we could remove the `None` from the second code fragment.